# Flot Charts Tool Tip Matching Y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to add tooltips to my flotcharts area and line graphs that will display the results of all on that Y axis, Also that it will display the tooltip for the cloest Y axis the mouse does not need to be exactly overal the point. for example look at [morris.js](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/). Lastly I would like to be able to trigger this for more then one graph on the same page [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RUKvk/)

here is an example of my plot()

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
                series: {
                    stack: true,
                    lines: { show: lines, fill: true, steps: steps },
                    bars: { show: bars, barWidth: 0.6 }
                }, yaxis: { min: 0}, xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%H:%M"},
                legend : { show: true, container : '#placeholder', noColumns: 9, margin: ['500px', 35]}
            });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking 3 questions here:

**Question 1:**

> I am trying to add tooltips to my flotcharts area and line graphs that will display the results of all on that Y axis

**Question 2:**

> Also that it will display the tooltip for the cloest Y axis the mouse does not need to be exactly overal the point. for example look at morris.js.

**Question 3:**

> Lastly I would like to be able to trigger this for more then one graph on the same page example

I'll answer Question 2, since the others will be fairly simple to figure out once you have Question 2 answered.

Basically, all you need to do to get the closest point is get the mouse position and compare it to all your data points' positions using flot's `pointOffset` function (See https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods). If the distance between the mouse and the point is the shortest, use it in your tooltip. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RUKvk/54/

*Question 1:* You'll need to modify my function slightly to store a list of points in stead of just one. If the distance is within a certain range, add it to the list.

*Question 3:* Multiple graphs should be pretty easily accomplished by calling this function on the other graph. You'll have to modify the function a bit to get it to work, but the principle is the same.

Comment: i love how someone finally answeres this the day after i have moved all my graphs to morris.

Comment: Lol! Well, thought I'd give it a shot anyway. I'm tempted to switch to morris as well now--thanks for the link! :)

Comment: morris charts are super slow in all broswers other then chrome so may have to move back to flot, but i am going to see if i can find out the performance issue with morris would be great if i can work with someone on it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm not the one who would be able to help you with that; but you're definitely in the right place to find someone who can.